# Why is System Settings > Input Devices > Mouse Controls messed up in Kubuntu 18.10?

Tags: kubuntu, mouse

I just installed kubuntu and the GUI of the panel "System Settings > Input Devices > Mouse Controls" looks like this:

[image]

Is this a known bug? I would like to use this panel to set the click settings to open folders on single click.

Edit: I should have mentioned I have a 4K screen (both internal and external monitors) and an intel onboard graphics card (Dell XPS 13 9350 laptop with i7 CPU).

I also realized some other graphics glitches, such as single pixel line shifts in chrome right in the center of the monitor:

[image]

This doesn't even show in a screenshot, so I had to use my phone to capture it.

I have used this exact configuration with Gentoo linux before for many years, where I have not seen any of these issues.

Comment: This is a fresh install of version 18.10 without any custom repositories. I added some information in an edit.

Comment: It's not available in the regular release. I'd like to test this version first before moving to a more experimental setup. But thanks a lot for the tip!

Comment: I understand your view but then 18.04, not 18.10, is the version that is recommended for a stable experience.